# Si es mayor a 5 entonces vale 6, si es menor vale 1, redondear Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estoy haciendo un paginador pero existen ciertas reglas. En el paginador, por medio de un input puedo ir a una página en específico, cada página tiene 20 resultados, por ejemplo, si escribo el 20 en el input me muestra los datos del 400 al 420, con esto no tengo tema.

Mi problema es a nivel visual.

Si escribo cualquier número entre 1 y 5, me debe de pintar un paginador así

```
 | 1 | | 2 | | 3 | | 4 | | 5 |
```

Si escribo entre el 6 y el 10 debería verse así

```
 | 6 | | 7 | | 8 | | 9 | | 10 |
```

El gran problema es que esta técnica la tengo que aplicar hasta las unidades de millar, y crear algo tan repetitivo nunca abacaré, por ejemplo, si elijo el número 2133 el paginador debería ser

```
 | 2131 | | 2132 | | 2133 | | 2134 | | 2135 |
```

y también debería funcionar si es 9467

```
 | 9466 | | 9467 | | 9468 | | 9469 | | 9470 |
```

Este paginador lo estoy haciendo con un `for`

```
var from = parseInt( $('#valor_input').val() );

for( var i = from; i <= ( from + 5 ); i++ ){
  ...
}
```

Aquí el problema es que, si mi valor `from` tiene un valor de 88, no quiero que inicie del 88, quiero que inicie del 86

Intenté con `var from = Math.round( parseInt( $('#valor_input').val() ) );`

Pero el número no se mueve, no se cómo redondear a 1 o a 6 dependiendo, en todo caso y si es menos complicado redondear a 0 y 5, si escribo 88, entonces valer 85 y de ahí sumar 5 números para que funcione el for

Comment: ¿Lo que tu quieres es que la página que seleccionas quede justo en el medio de tu paginador cierto? y ¿i es 1 o el ultimo número quede al inicio o al final?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo unico que tienes que hacer es sacar el mod y restarlo.  Algo asi:

```js
function paginacion() {
var from = parseInt( $('#valor_input').val() );

var diff = from % 5;

var newFrom = from - diff

for( var i = newFrom; i <= ( newFrom + 5 ); i++ ){
  console.log(i);
}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="valor_input" onBlur="paginacion()">
```